# SVN Dump/reload specific version with history

Tags: svn, svnadmin

I have an SVN repo on a file server (which I know is not the best practice) and one of the latest revisions is corrupted. I copied my repo locally and the path is C:\SVNLOCAL\SVNRepos. The corrupt commit is r 1070. I did a dump of my repo with svnadmin to r 1069 (`svnadmin dump C:\SVNLOCAL\SVNRepos -r 1069 > r1069.dump`) and load (`svnadmin load C:\SVNLOCAL\RECOVER < C:\SVNLOCAL\r1069.dump`) and loaded it to a new path but it shows no history even when I uncheck stop on rename.

Two questions, is can I just remove any revs after 1069 in the revs folders - SVNRepos\db\revs\1\1070+. I assume it's not that simple and I do need to do the dump and reload. If so, how do I do this while keeping the history intact.

Basically, I just want to revert to r1069, but if I try to do it against the repo it says 1070 has an unexpected end of file and stops dead. I am thinking a dump and load is my only alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **two(2)** revision arguments (start and end revision).
The dump command will dump **all** paths in start revision and stores the next revisions(until end revision) as deltas.

The correct command should be:

```
svnadmin dump  C:\SVNLOCAL\SVNRepos  -r 0:1069 >r1069.dump
```

You should not remove the last revision from your SVN Repo, as you may damage the repository. You will at least destroy the sqllite-cache if you have a svn 1.8.x repository.

Try to always to manipulate via dump file.

Comment: Peter, thanks. Figured I would blow up my repo by changing files directly but so frustrating to see that one corrupt commit revision screwing things up. I am attempting your fix now and will load it when it's done. If I get the repo intact up to r 1069 I'll mark your answer